# Django can't find existing document using ObjectId with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to update a document from my mLab using mongoengine. I have an existing ObjectId from a document but when I try to get it using the obtained id my search list is empty.

Here's my update code:

```
def update(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        _id = request.POST.get('_id',ObjectId())
        geometry = request.POST.get('geometry', '')
        properties = request.POST.get('properties','')
        try:
            route_test = Route.objects(id=ObjectId(_id))
            print(route_test)
            Route.objects(id=ObjectId(_id)).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
            return HttpResponse("Success!")

        except:
            return HttpResponse("Error!")
```

my `route_test` would contain nothing : [ ]. Is something wrong with my query? I even tried the following variation:

`Route.objects(id=_id), 
 Route.objects(_id=ObjectId(_id))`

Comment: You can try query with get or filter as your requirement : route_test = Route.objects.filter(id=_id) or route_test = Route.objects.get(id=_id) in Case of get you have to handle exception : from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

Comment: @Prafullkadam sadly this still doesn't fix the issue. my `_id` type is already an ObjectId so if I make it `id=_id` it's supposed to be correct... but it doesn't really get any document at all.

Comment: you are sure the _id has a value on line        `_id = request.POST.get('_id',ObjectId())`  ?

Comment: @SergiuZ yes. I guess I should delete this, I actually just made a work around since I can't figure this simple problem.